# Sitecore - how to show templates under specific folder, inside insert options context menu

Tags: sitecore, content-editor

Lets say the user itself is able to add new branch templates.

And on a homepage item, insert options must consist of items inside that branch templates folder.

In sitecore, insert options can only be set to specific items. When I select a folder as an insert option, sitecore shows that folder item (which is perfectly normal).

I need to make something like either showing items dynamically inside a specific folder, or setting the starting path of insert options browsing dialog.

Is any of this possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blog post: https://sitecorealekseyshevchenko.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/dynamic-insert-options/

Create '*Dynamic Insert Option*' template wich contains the only field '*Starting Path*' type of '*Droptree*' and source value is '*{3C1715FE-6A13-4FCF-845F-DE308BA9741D}*' - id of '*/sitecore/templates*' item.

Then add '*Dynamic Insert Option*' template to list of templates in '*Base template*' field of the template which should have dynamic insert options.

[image]

Patch '*uiGetMasters*' processor with such config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <processors>
      <uiGetMasters>
        <processor mode="on"
                   type="DynamicInsertOption.Processors.GetDynamicInsertOption, DynamicInsertOption"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.GetMasters.CheckSecurity, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </uiGetMasters>
    </processors>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Implement *GetDynamicInsertOption* processor:

```
namespace DynamicInsertOption.Processors
{
    using Sitecore.Data.Items;
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.Pipelines.GetMasters;

    public class GetDynamicInsertOption
    {
        public void Process(GetMastersArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

            var startingPath = args.Item["Starting Path"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startingPath))
            {
                for (int i = args.Masters.Count - 1; i > -1; i--) { args.Masters.RemoveAt(i); }

                var startingFolder = args.Item.Database.GetItem(startingPath);

                foreach (Item master in startingFolder.Children) { args.Masters.Add(master); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result see on pic below:

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you.

But the line `foreach (var master in args.Masters) { args.Masters.Remove(master); }` threw an error `collection is modified` so I replaced it with a for loop `for (int i = args.Masters.Count - 1; i > -1; i--) { args.Masters.RemoveAt(i); }`

Comment: Thanks for including the info in the answer, the blog post link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sitecore Insert Options Rules` instead of `Sitecore Insert Options`.

Find `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules` item and create new item under that node using `Insert Options Rule` template. Now edit the rule and set it to:

```
where the item is the Home item or one of its descendants
    and where the parent template is Folder
add YOUR_TEMPLATE insert option
```

There are plenty of other conditions you can use and the rule can be much more complex if you requirements demands it.

You can read more here: [Sitecore Insert Options Rules](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-insert-options-rules)

Comment: this has nothing to do with my problem.

the issue is that 

"add YOUR_TEMPLATE insert option"

must be set statically to a specific object, i'm looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: I think I haven't understood your requirements correctly. Can you maybe try to describe it in more extended way or give some example of what you need?

Comment: instead of setting static items as insert options, i want to assign a folder and  display the child items under that folder as insert options. because there will be additions and deletions, the insert options will have to change dynamically.

Comment: @Batu check my solution. It gives ability to choose a folder and display the children under that folder as insert options.

Comment: @AlekseyShevchenko yeah i saw your solution is directly on point, applying it right now.

Comment: @Batu pretty good. if it is suited for you please apply my answer as right.